# Can I nominate other candidates for moderator?

Tags: support, moderators, election

Great that we've got [moderator elections](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election)!

Maybe I've missed something but I can't see how to nominate *someone else*. Is that possible? There are a handful of really dedicated users here (just look at the [high rep list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)) and in the top ten only one is a moderator.

I'd like to see a few more moderators there and so would like to nominate one or two of those top ten-ers.

Comment: I do wonder how you could contact a user and encourage them to run, if they don't frequent chat enough to use that. Perhaps find a meta post of theirs and (ab)use that?

Comment: I for one welcome our new Scifi overlords. Also I believe in term limits.

Comment: @tony - you can abuse a non-meta post as well. Once the contact is established, delete the "Hey you!" comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If someone is interested in the job, they can add their name, but, as was discussed in chat earlier today, you can't nominate someone else.  (And some of those people higher up on that high rep list have specifically said they do not want to be moderators.  That includes 2 of the top 4 on that list.)

But you're pretty high up on that list, so why not nominate yourself?

Comment: *"But you're pretty high up on that list, so why not nominate yourself?"* Nice idea, but sorry, that conflicts with my programming...

Comment: And apparently the answer is essentially the same for many of the others that are also high up on that list.  For example, I've said that I'm at the computer for work for now, but that won't be for but so long, and when that time comes, I won't be able to devote much time to the board.  Lots of people use a board like this as a break during things like compile time but would have trouble giving it the attention a moderator would have to give it.

Comment: To add another one, I'm #8 at the moment, and have never had any interest in being a moderator (I can't say I never will, but I won't change my mind in the next week).

Comment: BTW Jeff explained the reasoning over at math: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/what-is-the-reason-for-insisting-on-self-nomination

Comment: I, for one, won't nominate myself because in the place of a moderator you would have a programmer! Not dark but beautiful and terrible as the Morn! Treacherous as the Seas! Stronger than the foundations of the Earth! All shall love me and despair!

Comment: @DavRob60 - just for the mental image of you as Galadriel, you won't get my vote

Comment: I'm technically a programmer (though I'm now forced to do more management that I'd strictly like). I already moderate on slashdot and I nominated myself yesterday for scifi. I too have doubts about how much time I can devote to this, but I think I should at least give it a try.